# what are the steps for submitting android application into Facebook for approval

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have created an **Android** application which uses **Facebook** Authentication.

When posting a text message through my application, it appears on my wall.
But others cannot see that post even though it is publicly available.

It seems I need to submit my application to **Facebook** to allow others to see my post.

Can anyone help me, how can I submit my application for **Facebook** approval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Facebook developer** official site and login and then select the Particular app and go to **Status & Review** and `turn ON Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?` check box and remember it'll take to 2-3 hours for reflection. see the below image

[image]

As i faced the same issue in past and solved it by this way.Hope this works for you.